# Precision loss in shared multiprocessing array?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I am experimenting with the multiprocessing Array type to share a writeable object between processes. I have read the many cautions about doing so, but believe it is necessary in my application due to physical memory constraints.

It appears that there is some precision loss in using Array, however, that I can't quite figure out. Here is a reproducible example that compares the result of summing a series of random arrays via multiprocessing Arrays (with locks) and directly:

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array 

# Initialize multiprocessing Array and numpy view
n = 100
m = 100
num_reps = 100
arr = Array('d', n*m)
shared_result = np.ctypeslib.as_array(arr.get_obj()).reshape(n,m)

# Function to add random arrays to multiprocessing array
def adder(i,shared_res=shared_result,arr=arr):
    tmp = np.random.rand(n,m)
    with arr.get_lock():
        shared_result[:,:] += tmp
    return tmp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Parallel(n_jobs=10) as parallel:       
        tst = parallel(delayed(adder)(k) for k in range(num_reps))

# Compare results from multiprocessing Array vs. explicit sum
print(np.mean(shared_result - sum(tst)))
```

This produces:

```
9.73443547991e-17
```

while I expected 0. Is there some precision issue I'm not seeing here?

Update: It appears that the issue is with `Parallel`. If instead of using that, you do

```
tst = [adder(k) for k in range(num_reps)]
print(np.mean(np.abs(shared_result - sum(tst))))
```

as suggested below by abarnert, you get 0. So what's up with pickling in Parallel that's dropping some precision?

Comment: If you run this same code without `Parallel`, just `tst = [adder(k) for k in range(num_reps)]`, does that always give 0?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's the shared array that's off, not the `tmp` that you return from `adder` through `Parallel` (which means it has to be pickled and unpickled)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are right -- I just added an update above that shows the issue is with `Parallel`.

Comment: What versions of Python and joblib? If it's Python 2.x, maybe it's using pickle format 0, which IIRC effectively means a repr/eval round trip on floats. Although that seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: This python 3.5.5 and joblib 0.11.

Comment: Oh well, that rules out one easy possibility…

Comment: FWIW: With Python 3.6.4, joblib 0.12.1 and numpy 1.14.5, I get errors with the code shown in the question (several occurrences of `EOFError: Ran out of input`, and some `loky` errors).  If I add the argument `backend='threading'` to the `Parallel()` call, the code runs and prints 0.0.

Comment: Floating point addition is not (in general) associative--the order in which the terms are added matters.  If the `shared_sum` is computed in a different order than `sum(tst)`, the results are likely to be different.  In the cases where you get 0.0 as the output, you can get a nonzero output by first executing `random.shuffle(tst)` before computing `sum(tst)`.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of your original data is 0 to 1.  Your error is about 1e-16.

This is totally normal, as a 64-bit floating point number has about 15 significant digits.  So an error of 1e-16 on a calculation with magnitude 0.5 is to be expected.

As for why the error does not occur when using inter-process communication, it may be because your local CPU uses an 80-bit internal floating point format (as x87 has always done), whereas floating point numbers sent between processes are going to be limited to 64 bits of precision.

There are some special techniques to sum sets of floating point numbers more accurately.  Here is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested using the inter-process sum anyways.

Comment: @Evan: Of course.  There's nothing wrong with it--you just can't assume that floating point calculations are exact (multiprocessing or not).